# Simple algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Can someone more intelligent than me please solve this simple math conversion that I need to accomplish within javascript.

If I have an ordered array of numbers say...

```
var values = [99, 101, 102, 103, 104];
var low = 99;
var high = 104;
```

...and I need the highest value in the array to be pushed to a new array as the value 1, and the second highest value to be pushed to the new array as 2, etc., so the new array is...

```
var newArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6];
```

I can make a hack version that works but I need a solution that will work on arrays with diverse number values. Appreciate the help!

Comment: what is the logic behind pushing `1` instead of `104`. If there is no reason then simply `Array.fill` will work

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this

```js
var values = [99, 101, 102, 103, 104];
var low = 99;
var high = 104;

var newOutputArr = [];
newOutputArr.push(1);


for (var j=values.length - 2; j>=0; j--) {
  var cal = Math.abs(values[j] - high) + 1;
  newOutputArr.push(cal);
}

console.log(newOutputArr);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could map the delta of high value and value plus one and reverse the array.

```js
var values = [99, 101, 102, 103, 104],
    low = 99,
    high = 104,
    result = values
        .map(v => high + 1 - v)
        .reverse();
 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Small question, with a callback function one can also get the index and the array, is that possible with the arrow function?

Comment: the callback has the same signature for arrow functions as for standard functions, like `(item, index, array) => ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that ... I didn't understand to enclose the parameters with parenthesis.

Comment: maybe you have a look here, too: [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks again ... actually been at that page before but obviously missed (read lazy :) the line `// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name`. Never had the time to dig deeper into all these new stuff. They weren't available when I started coding 25 years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

With `map` and `reverse`, you could subtract each value from the first and then add 1

Stack snippiet

```js
var values = [99, 101, 102, 103, 104];

var new_values = values.reverse().map(function (val, idx, arr) {
    return (arr[0] - val + 1);
})

console.log(new_values);
```

---

Or with an arrow function (this won't work with IE though)

```js
var values = [99, 101, 102, 103, 104];

var new_values = values.reverse().map((val,idx,arr) => arr[0] - val + 1);

console.log(new_values);
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Array.prototype.reduce`. And forgo the use of the `low` and `high` variables. Then you can use any sorted array. Something like this:

```js
const values = [99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 108, 199, 200, 234, 235];

const newArray = values.reduce( (i, v, a, b) => {
  
  if(a === 0) i.push(1)
  else i.push(i[a - 1] + v - b[a-1])
  
  return i
    
}, []);

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a single pass of `.reduceRight()` is sufficient.

```js
var values = [99, 101, 102, 103, 104],
    low    = 99,
    high   = 104,
    result = values.reduceRight((r,v) => r.concat(high-v+1), []);
console.log(result);
```